# Promote JSE using Community ads

Tags: discussion

I just read about Community Promotion Ads, and seeing that most Joomla-related questions still are [posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/joomla), would it be possible to create an ad and suggest it to StackOverflow (or another related site)?

If that's withing the scope of Community Promotion Ads, maybe we could have a mini-voting here in order to agree on a nice banner?

**Update:**

#### [Image requirements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014) from SO:

- The image that you create must be 220 pixels by 250 pixels
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white

Comment: Do you have a link where the process is described? It would be great to have such an ad.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/

Comment: Sounds like a great idea to me!

Comment: I don't have much time to go through the blog post, but still it sounds good to me. I guess, all we need, is someone with graphics skills to design the banner.

Comment: @johanpw - lol well we have both failed so far :) Both used `.jpg`....oops

Comment: @Lodder - how sloppy of us :). We'll have to save as `.png` when we send it to SO. But which banner do we use? I was kind of hoping for more votes/feedback on the banners from other JSE users as well... Anyone?

Comment: @johanpw - I would say either your first one or my second one (without the dark blue at the top)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick idea, feel free to comment or suggest changes. Or post another image, 220x250 pixels.

[image: Joomla StackExchange]

Should I add a small StackExchange logo to make it clear that it's part of the SE network?

Here's another version with logo. I'm not sure if the border is necessary or not, but I think it is if the background is white.

[image: Joomla StackExchange]

Comment: I like those very much. Could you true the blue border/outline **with** the Stachexchange logo at the bottom?

Comment: @Lodder, sure, I've updated it. I kept the thin border though, I like it better than the thick one.

Comment: `It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).` I don't think advertising Joomla beta meets these requirements for an ad :/

Comment: @Lodder, I guess you're right, our ads doesn't meet those requirements. Too bad. I really think there should be some way to promote SE communities on related sites, though.

Answer (score 2):

Another few quick mockups:

[image]    [image]

Comment: Nice and elegant, personally I like the first one best.

Comment: I think we should get an ad out there ASAP, visits to JSE seems to have stopped at about 1191/day, and 2014 is almost over... I suggest you publish your second alternative to [SE Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014) (maybe without the dark blue at the top), and then we encourage everyone to upvote it (I think 6 upvotes or more are required for it to be published).

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the SE banner for the FB page... there is also a SO FB page... https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange & https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow

Is there a FB JSE page ?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: Does other SE communities have their own FB page? I'm not sure what benefit there is for JSE to have one. The SE page posts links to popular questions (and some feature changes). The SO page hasn't been active since 2012...